# java https connection and security popup

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection, securitymanager

My application is an signed applet and it is compiled with java 1.6

In my app, i making an https get request. Even though i ignore the certificate validation, JRE still shows me an security pop up. 
When i try the same request through internet explorer, it does not show any security warning.

**1)Is there anything i can do programatically to make this securty popup gone?** 

**2)Even though i accept all certificates, why does JRE shows an warning pop up?.**

Here is the code i ignore the certificate validity:

```
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };
    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = null;
        try {
             sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            MainScreen.toConsole(ex);
             sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        }
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

here is the screenshot of the security warning:
[image]

Comment: Is your certificate signed by a CA that the browser knows?

Comment: applet is sign by verisign, sertificate on the ssl is rapidssl.

Comment: as i said when i make the same request via the browser. There is no security warning.

Answer (score 1):

Only think I can think of: make sure that the CA certificate for rapidssl is in your java certificate store. Check [this guide](http://www.dekho.com.au/help/32/default.htm?turl=Documents/addingacertificateintothejavacertificatestore.htm) out. I know it's in your browser, but it might not be  known to java.